# Can not use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function?

Tags: pine-script

How would I code this to get around the error "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function." Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

```
res4 = input(title="time frame", type=input.resolution, defval="240")

len = input(14)
th = input(20)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0



SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange


SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus



SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)


//security function
DIPlus4H = security("USDCAD", res4, DIPlus)
DIMinus4H = security("USDCAD", res4, DIMinus)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the error message is clear. You cannot use mutable objects with the `security` function.

The workaround is, move all your calculations related to that specific variable that you want to use in your `security()` call into a function and then cal that function in `security()`.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
res4 = input(title="time frame", type=input.resolution, defval="240")

len = input(14)
th = input(20)

get_DIPlus() =>
    TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
    DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
    DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0
    SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
    SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus
    DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100

//security function
DIPlus4H = security("USDCAD", res4, get_DIPlus())
plot(DIPlus4H)
```